# remove case sensitivity from search jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove case sensitivity from my search criteria. If I typed lower-case letter I want it to search through both lower-case and upper-case.

[My plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/w0GaOnVrGArwB06sqpln/)

```
$('#search').click(function(){
    $('.contact-name').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.contact-name:contains("' + txt + '")').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:contains` selector is case sensitive by default. If you want to make it case insensitive you would need to implement your own logic using `filter()` to make both the text of the element and value to search for the same case. Something like this:

```
$('#search').click(function(){
    $('.contact-name').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.contact-name').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(txt.toLowerCase()) != -1;
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: Man why are you sooo fast? `:(`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

`:contains` is case sensitive therefore it is not working in your case

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dbpz4nwa/)

```
$('#search').click(function(){

    $('.contact-name').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val().toLowerCase();
    $('.contact-name').each(function(i,n){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if(text.indexOf(txt) > -1)
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```